# Add comment to WinRar archive with batch file

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, winrar

When using Winrar we have the ability to add a comment to an archive. I am using a simple batch script to backup a folder. Is there a way to add a comment to the rar archive with the batch file?

Preferably I would like to add the comments through the command prompt window rather than having to use an external file to load the comments.

This is the batch file.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" -r  a -agYYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM "C:\Folder" "B:\Archive" -ep1 -r -m5
pause
```

It will archive everything in C:\Folder to B:\Archive

Comment: It could be worth it to clear up your rar line. You have `-r` two times and according to the help of `rar.exe` you got your folder/file parameters in reverse. Right now it should create a `C:\Folder<date>` archive from the files in `B:\Archive` in addition it would be a good idea to move those switches to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably still the easiest to do it with a file but you can just generate it on the fly. An example could look like this:

```
@echo off
SET /P comment=Comment:
echo %comment% > C:\Temp\message.txt
rar.exe a -zC:\Temp\message.txt "test.rar" "C:\TestFiles"
del C:\Temp\message.txt
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET /P comment=Comment: seems to need a manual Enter-press, otherwise the command just waits...
```

Trying to solve that for you all... I got stuck.

So I made another solution which is easier and works just as good, if not better?

```
@echo off
echo Winrar Incremental Wallets Backup E: > C:\Temp\winrar.message.E.txt
```

Run your rar-command with the following option added: `-zC:\Temp\winrar.message.E.txt`

And to keep it clean, you could finish the batch file with:

```
del /F /Q C:\Temp\winrar.message.E.txt
```

That was all for my solution.

I am on Windows 2019 and I just cannot get the SET /P working properly (or I am too dumb)*

- When it comes to SET /P and why it fails for me... I have no idea and if you know anything let me know. This article was very interesting, but even that did not work for me (https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_inputvalidation_setp.php). Code he gave:

  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET /P var="Type anything here:"
  ECHO .!var!.
  ECHO strip quotes: .!var:"=!.
  REM If you really want to reject the variable with any quotation mark...
  ECHO !var! | FIND """" >NUL && SET var=
  REM That's it.

I also tried: `SET /P comment=Comment: < nul` to skip the obligatory Enter press but without a way to use SET /P (by me), I cannot say that that could fix the original solution of having to press Enter. Main problem with SET /P I have is that things like `ECHO .!var!.`, `ECHO !var!`, `ECHO %comment%` and even `ECHO %%comment%%` actually do not gave any results. The variables are not set. Only when I manually type the comment-string myself, I can get results. Otherwise, it is a mess :)